# Is this expected hard disk speed? 22.6MB/s

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, performance

I have a Lenovo [Y470](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/ww/pdf/Y470_Datasheet_US.pdf). The hard disk is 500GB 7200rpm and, while copying files from one directory to another, I am getting 22.6MB/s speed.

[image]

- Is this slow or average?
- Can I do something to improve this speed?

Comment: That's not unusual for a file copy on the same partition, and there's not much you can do to significantly speed up a large file copy like that other than not doing anything else to minimize other disk I/O while the copy continues.

Comment: Just giving rough estimates.

Comment: ok, that means 22.6MB/s is not slow. Am I right?

Comment: uhm, i'd say that's very very slow. Download [HDTune](http://www.hdtune.com/) and run an error scan so we can see if there's any bad blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the file types, that's not terrible for platters - especially since you are reading from and copying to the same drive.

Some folks on [Overclockers](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=678783) were discussing speeds on modern discs, which were in the 50+ range.  But that's probably sequential, and really dependent on the manufacturer (and not across the same drive).

Looks like you're copying media items of varying sizes, which won't likely be sequential reads/writes - so that will be significantly slower.

You're probably in the right range for what/where you're copying - if you are concerned about it being a bad drive, try [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/) to verify your speeds for various operations.  Let us see that to give you a better guess since Windows approximates values (and generally does so poorly).